# Is there any difference between "there is no possibility to do something" and "it's impossible to do something"?

Tags: expression-choice

If the context is important, I'm building a website along with other people. One of my colleagues wrote the following error message:

> There is no possibility to edit invalid something.

It sounds a bit strange to me, and I think

> It's impossible to edit invalid something.

is more appropriate in this case, but I don't have any arguments.

Comment: Please don't use "smth" here.

Comment: I believe the OP's use of "smth" was to keep the title short, or at least shorter. I don't see anything wrong in that. @tchrist

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any difference in meaning.

> "there is no possibility to do" is more **formal**
>
> "it's impossible to do" **informal**

Comment: Please don't use "smth" here.